# CSS Navbar changes size on different sized screens

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am doing a website for school, and it's been going well. The only problem I am stuck on is this: The navbar changes size on different sized screens. It's most readily apparent when zooming out, but it is slightly off on different screens.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean: 
https://docs.google.com/a/g.ccsd.net/file/d/0B_Sda_-LouAKbnVKVHhMSW5yeXc/edit?usp=sharing
Please note that the left side, which is the problem, moves around a lot depending on the scale. The above image is only one example.

This is my CSS:

```
ul {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Times;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  z-index: 150;
  /* min-width: 739px;
  max-width: 739px; */
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
li ul { display: none; }
ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 7px solid #CC4D4D;
  padding: 25px 26.45px 30px 26.45px; /*top right bottom left*/
  background: #333333;
  margin-left: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover { background: #757575; }
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a { background: #757575; }
li:hover li a:hover { background: #757575; }
```

This is my HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="showcase.html">Showcase</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="faculty.html">Faculty</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="ro.html">Mrs. Rosarita Olvina</a></li>
    <li><a href="cp.html">Mrs. Christine Pavesich</a></li>
    <li><a href="fv.html">Mr. Francisco Virella</a></li>
    <li><a href="fv.html">Mrs. Susan Williams</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="programs.html">Program Areas</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="graphics.html">Graphic Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li>
    <li><a href="video.html">Video Production</a></li>
    <li><a href="animation.html">Animation</a></li>
    <li><a href="art.html">Art</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="whatwedo.html">What We Do</a></li>
    <li><a href="wherewego.html">Where We Go</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="default.html">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you for any help.

***I tried first answer, it didn't work, but I may be doing it very wrong.

Comment: Can you provide some more code, at least for the container element and header? That would help.

Comment: For anyone who wants the answer, it isn't what KappNossi said, even though that did help me a bit with formatting. What I did was remove the "padding: 25px 26.45px 30px 26.45px;" padding and just centered the text. It turned out the problem wasn't the BOXES scaling, but the TEXT scaling. Removing the padding allows the text size to fluctuate without changing the box size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not necessarily within the menu. Rather the whole menu (or its container) needs to be placed properly.

As far as I can tell from the code you've given, the floats may also play a part in fixing this. The whole menu and nested ULs are floating. My suggestion would be to avoid these floats and work with "display: inline-block" instead to get the horizontal arrangement.

After streamlining the menu entries like that, you can properly position your whole menu container in the surrounding HTML.

In case you don't already use it: Firebug or Chromebug plugins are really handy for identifying errors like this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Didn't work. Maybe I'm doing it wrong though. Also, it's already in a container div, I just didn't include that in the code snippet.

Comment: Well the solution depends on how the surrounding is set up. First, try to properly position your container div. It should probably float left to always stick to the left side of your content pane. Apply your color scheme of the menu buttons to the container (black color, red border on top). When that's done and the div stays in the correct position, continue with the ul and li elemens within the container which should now only need size and hover color styling. Like I said before, try to use inline-block instead of floats, because it saves you some headaches.